# Apex trigger - is this the best approach?

Tags: apex, bestpractice

I'm getting up to speed with Apex - I have written a trigger that works, but is this the approach that an experienced coder would take?

I have a custom object (vist_detail__c) which has a lookup to Contracts.  We create tasks on the custom object.  I want an alert when the task date is beyond the Contract end date.

(The commenting shows that I began by adding the trigger.new IDs to a set but then I couldn't figure out how to access the Task date to compare with Contract end date so I dropped the set idea)

```
trigger MaCwTaskTriggerTest on Task (after insert, after update) {
    system.debug('Hey Dude');
//    Set<Id> cwIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task aTask: Trigger.new)
    {
//    cwIds.add(aTask.WhatId);
//      system.debug('Added to set: '+aTask.WhatId);
//  }
//    for (Id i : cwIds) {
//        system.debug('Id in list is '+i);

        vist_Detail__c vD = [SELECT contract__r.endDate FROM vist_Detail__c 
                                    WHERE Id = :aTask.WhatId];
          Date cEndDate = vD.contract__r.endDate;
          system.debug('Contract end date: '+cEndDate);
          if (aTask.ActivityDate > cEndDate) {
            system.debug('Task Date greater than Contract end date');                                  
            }
          else {
            system.debug('Task Date less than or equal to Contract end date');                                  
               }
    }
}
```

It works, but is it best practice?

Any suggestions on how best to alert a user? The task is created by workflow.  I can't see a situation where these tasks would be created in bulk in which case would emailing user be sensible?  I have the Apex for that.

Many Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish with the trigger.  The trigger will only fire when there's been a change to Task. So if you're trying to determine if a Task is beyond its due date, a Trigger isn't going to notify you. Instead, you'll need to run a class to check all Tasks where the status is open on Tasks related to `vist_Detail__c`.

Comment: Check out [David Liu's tutorials](http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/11/23/the-three-most-common-governor-limits-and-why-youre-getting-them/) for more info on the query inside a loop issue.

Comment: Have you thought about using your trigger to populate a date field on the task, then create a workflow (triggered when the field is populated) to send a [time based](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) email alert if the task status is still open at the scheduled time? Time based workflows only send alerts / update fields etc. if their criteria are still met at the scheduled time so include Text(Status) = 'Open'. It should be easier to maintain than code.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I want to notify a user when a Task is created with a Date that is beyond the end date of the customer contract so that engineers are not despatched to a site where the contract has ended and the customer refuses to pay.

Comment: @alex - David Liu's tutorials are really good - I need to watch and read them again!
Good idea about triggering a workflow - I will update an invisible checkbox and use that to trigger an email if a Task has been created which is after the customer contract has ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Query inside for loop

**Problem 2:**

Without checking the `whatId` of `Task` to be Id of `Vist_Detail__c`, the query can return 0 records and throw

> List has no rows for assignment error

Look for documentation to rectify the above mentioned errors.

Hope it helps. Happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

Good catch - Thanks @vigneshwaran.

Like this?

```
trigger MaCwTaskTriggerTest on Task (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> tIds = new Set<Id>(); // Task IDs
    Set<Id> cwIds = new Set<Id>(); // Task WhatIDs
    Map<Id, Task> TMap;
    Map<Id, vist_Detail__c> vDMap;


    for (Task aTask: Trigger.new)
    {
      cwIds.add(aTask.WhatId);
      system.debug('Task.WhatId added to set: '+aTask.WhatId);
      tIds.add(aTask.Id);
      system.debug('Task.Id added to set: '+aTask.Id);
    }

    TMap = new Map<Id, Task>([SELECT Id, ActivityDate FROM Task 
                                    WHERE Id in :tIds]);
    vDMap = new Map<Id, vist_Detail__c>([SELECT Id, contract__r.endDate FROM vist_Detail__c 
                                    WHERE Id in :cwIds]);
    system.debug('vDMap = '+vDMap);

        if (vDMap.size() > 0) {
            for (Task aTask: Trigger.new) {
              system.debug ('Task Activity Date: '+TMap.get(aTask.Id).ActivityDate);
              system.debug ('Contract End Date: '+vDMap.get(aTask.WhatId).contract__r.endDate);
                if (TMap.get(aTask.Id).ActivityDate > vDMap.get(aTask.WhatId).contract__r.endDate)
                system.debug('Task Date greater than Contract end date');                                  
            else
                system.debug('Task Date less than or equal to Contract end date');                                  
            }
        }
       else system.debug('No VDs selected');
    }
```

Comment: this should be posted as an update to the original post, not as an answer

Comment: and `TMap` is unnecessary as you have access to `Trigger.newMap`